# Append table headers in table using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

I am trying to append table headers in a html table.

Its appending, however its inserting a break and appending in next line. How to overcome this?

Plz help. Thanks in advance. Check my code below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="test">
  <thead>
    <th> Column 1</th>
    <th> Column 2</th>
    <th> Column 3</th>
  </thead>       
  </table>
  <button> Click Me</button>
  <script>
    $('#test >thead').append('<th> Column 4</th>');
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7):

***Reason why code is not working:-***

If you look the rendered HTML *of your given code* on browser console then you will get that `<tr></tr>` is *automatically introduce* around `<th></th>` and that's why jQuery appending `<th> Column 4</th>` in newline.*(some smart enough browsers did them automatically to make HTML structure correct)*

You need to do like below (Add `tr` in your HTML yourself and change jQuery):-

```
$('#test >thead tr').append('<th> Column 4</th>');
```

Working example:-

```js
$('#test >thead tr').append('<th> Column 4</th>');
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table id="test">
      <thead>
        <tr><!-- add it yourself-->
         <th> Column 1</th>
         <th> Column 2</th>
         <th> Column 3</th>
       </tr><!-- tr ended -->
      </thead>       
    </table>
    <button> Click Me</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

1) Missing `tr` in inside the thead .

2)  your trying to append `$('#test >thead')` inside the thead .but in browser you can see there was a tr enclosed your columns name .so it will append outside the `tr` . so you need to append like this  `$('#test >thead tr').append('<th> Column 4</th>');`

```js
    $('#test >thead tr').append('<th> Column 4</th>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="test">
  <thead>
    <tr>
    <th> Column 1</th>
    <th> Column 2</th>
    <th> Column 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>       
  </table>
  <button> Click Me</button>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is more correct because it is not missing the tr in the HTML.

Answer (score 4):

```js
$('#test > thead tr').append('<th> Column 4</th>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="test">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th> Column 1</th>
    <th> Column 2</th>
    <th> Column 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
<button> Click Me</button>
```

1. Needs a `tr`

Comment: really? was it like 2 mins i was answer the same time you did im pretty sure you had times like this and this doesnt deserve a down vote. this is self righteous down voting

Comment: This is more correct because it is not missing the tr in the HTML.

Answer (score 2):

This code will also be helpful

```
<table id="test">
    <thead>
        //<tr> tag added which is missing in your code 
        <tr>
            <th> Column 1</th>
            <th> Column 2</th>
            <th> Column 3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
<button> Click Me</button>
```

```
//below is the code inside <script></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
    $('#test').find('thead tr').append('<th> Column 4</th>');
</script>
```

Comment: it will append all the tr in table . he need to append in thead>tr only  @Divya